# Can i use Helper @can in controller?

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatables

i have this code in my controller

```
public function index()
   {
       if(request()->ajax())
       {
           return datatables()->of(User::latest()->get())
               ->addColumn('action', function($data){
                   $button = '<a href="#" name="show" id="'.$data->id.'" class="show-modal"><i title="Visualizar" style="color: #00897b;" class="material-icons">visibility</i></a>';
                   $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                   $button .= '<a href="#" name="edit" id="'.$data->id.'" class="edit-modal"><i title="Editar" style="color: black;" class="material-icons">edit</i></a>';
                   $button .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                   $button .= '<a href="#" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete-modal"><i title="Excluir" style="color: red;" class="material-icons">delete</i></a>';
                   return $button;
               })
               ->rawColumns(['action'])
               ->make(true);
       }
       return view('admin.usuarios.index');
   }
```

Can i use helper @can in button? Like this:

```
$button = '@can ('isAdmin') <a href="#" name="show" id="'.$data->id.'" class="show-modal"><i title="Visualizar" style="color: #00897b;" class="material-icons">visibility</i></a> @endCan';
```

Comment: you can't use it in your controller, it's blade directive work only inside`.blade.php`. You can use gate and policies here instead. or simple check `$user->isAdmin`

Comment: Use a function, to check user->isAdmin, before the return datatables(), right? or inside $button?

Comment: It depends on how you have defined your role, in same table or different. If different you can create a relation and access it like `$user->role()->isAdmin`. If same, you can use `$user->isAdmin`. You can also define a function in your User model. that will return true if is Admin, false otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the **can** method.

```
$request->user()->can('delete', $data)
```

Here I am explaining it according to your question

```
if (request()->user()->can('isAdmin', $data)) {
   $button .= '<a href="#" name="delete" id="'.$data->id.'" class="delete-modal"><i title="Excluir" style="color: red;" class="material-icons">delete</i></a>';
}

return $button;
```

Policy

```
public function isAdmin(User $user, Post $post)
{
  return $user->id === $post->user_id;
}
```